# Are csv uploads to a website with SSL secure?

Tags: security, ssl, data-security

I would like to upload a csv file with sensitive data to a website that allows csv uploads. The website is secured with SSL however, I am uncertain whether the csv file upload would be transmitted securely?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file to a website over SSL, the file is encrypted while it is transmitted from your device to the website's server. This means that anyone who might intercept the transmission would not be able to read the contents of the file.
If you are concerned about the security of your data, you might consider using a file sharing service that allows you to password-protect your files or encrypt them before uploading. This will add an extra layer of security to your data and help to ensure that it is protected from unauthorized access.

- Dropbox
- Google Drive
- OneDrive

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. Could you perhaps point me to a reputable source that supports your answer?

Comment: This is a standard protection that TLS provides. You can find numerous sources on the Internet about it. You can also inspect the traffic in your browser to see more about what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply however, the only reason I asked this question was due to the internet not having immediate, conclusive evidence supporting your assertion. The browser inspection suggestion does help though